# Files are corrupted when they are retrieved from database

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload, corruption

In my website, I want to allow the user to upload files (they will be stored in a database) and then allow them to download the uploaded files after that. The uploading process is done without errors and they are saved in binary.

The downloading process also works but the downloaded files are corrupted !
Any idea why?

The uploading code:

```
<?php require_once('Connections/databasestudents.php'); ?>
<?php

$fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$tmpName  = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$fileSize = $_FILES['file']['size'];
$fileType = $_FILES['file']['type'];

$fp      = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
$content = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
$content = addslashes($content);

$studentId = $_POST['studentId'];
fclose($fp);

$query = "INSERT INTO file (studentId, fileName, fileType, fileContent ) ".
"VALUES ('$studentId', '$fileName', '$fileType', '$content')";

mysql_select_db($database_databasestudents, $databasestudents);
mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed'); 

header("Location: students.php");
die();

?>
```

The download code:

```
<?php require_once('Connections/databasestudents.php'); ?>
<?php
mysql_select_db($database_databasestudents, $databasestudents);
$query = 'SELECT fileName, fileContent, fileType, LENGTH(fileContent) as fileSize from file WHERE id="'. $_GET ['id'].'";';

$Recordset1 = mysql_query($query, $databasestudents) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1);

$result = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH);
$size = $row['fileSize'];
$type = $row['fileType'];
$name =$row['fileName'];
$fileContent = $row['fileContent'];
echo $size . "". $type . " ". $name;

header("Content-length: $size");
header("Content-type: $type");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$name");
echo $fileContent;

mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: Why are you uploading files inside your db in the first place, instead of their path?

Comment: table name: file. Field: fileContent . Type: longblob

Comment: I don't know how to do it :s

Comment: mysql_* is deprecated. I recommend not using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured it out .. jus removing this line from the download code:

```
echo $size . "". $type . " ". $name;
```

Comment: You still have an SQL injection in the download code, and the code is terribly inefficient. Please do consider using PDO - the example code I linked in my answer is nearly exactly what you need, so it should not be too much work.

Comment: well I would like to but I'm new to both php and sql and I'm not sure how to modify the code .. I'm worried I'll destroy what is working now

Comment: Make a copy of your code before you change anything, and then try it - it's the best way to learn! If you don't understand something, look up the documentation on http://www.php.net/ (you probably should read a bit about PDO - look at the examples and try to understand them, it's hard now put it will help you a lot in the future - it's worth it!)

Answer (score 2):

1. Use PDOs and prepared statements. This may fix the issue, and it will fix the SQL injection vulnerability in the download code (which currently allows people to hack your database).
2. PDO has "large objects" (LOBs) support meant for exactly what you are doing. It will be much more efficient than what you are currently doing. The [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lobs.php) provides excellent example code which does more or less exactly what you want.